# Prove by definition that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{n^3}{1.2^n} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove by definition that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{n^3}{1.2^n} = 0$

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Also, some would consider your post rude because it is a command ("Prove"), not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.

Comment: The question as stated could be answered by saying "I define the limit to be as given" - one interpretation of a proof by definition, though not a useful one. It would help if you gave the definition you are working with - sometimes the act of writing down the definition in the context of a particular problem helps to show the way forward.

Answer (score 1):

First a lemma: $n^3<1.2^\frac{n}{2}$ for $n>1000$.

The proof is by induction. Google or any other calculator will verify that $1.2^{500}>1000^3$. Suppose $n^3<1.2^{\frac{n}{2}}$, then
$$(n+1)^3 = n^3+3n^2+3n+1 < n^3(1+\frac{7}{n}) < 1.2^{\frac{n}{2}}(1+\frac{7}{n})<1.2^{\frac{n+1}{2}},$$
since $(1+\frac{7}{n})^2 = 1+\frac{14}{n}+\frac{49}{n^2} < 1.2$ for $n\geq 1000$.

Now for the actual proof:
Let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $N=\min(1000,\lceil -2\log_{1.2}(\epsilon)\rceil)$, then for any $n>N$:$$\left|\frac{n^3}{1.2^n}\right| < \frac{1.2^\frac{n}{2}}{1.2^n} = 1.2^{-\frac{n}{2}}<1.2^{-\frac{1}{2}(-2\log_{1.2}(\epsilon))}= \epsilon.$$
This concludes the proof by the definition of the limit.